# Twitter API Limit

Tags: api, twitter

I have heard that Twitter limits the number of API calls a third party app can make per hour. I believe the limit is around 100.  My question is, does that limit apply per user, or is it 100 calls per app?  100 for the entire application seems very low, but I wanted to make sure and I couldn't find my answer in the documentation I was reading.  Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting

> The default rate limit for calls to
>   the REST API is 150 requests per hour.
>   The REST API does account- and
>   IP-based rate limiting. Authenticated
>   API calls are charged to the
>   authenticating user's limit while
>   unauthenticated API calls are deducted
>   from the calling IP address'
>   allotment.

Answer (score 4):

The limit as of Oct. 8, 2009 is 150 requests per hour per ip/account. Sending tweets doesn't go against that limit.

However, you can get your ip(s) and account whitelisted, which gets you up to 20,000 requests per hour per ip/account. To do that, go to: http://twitter.com/help/request_whitelisting

**Note:** You MUST be in production to be whitelisted.

For those of us in beta (myself included) all is not lost as Twitter has an API to check how many requests/hour you have left for that ip/account (the api is called rate_limit_status).

(Sorry, I'd post more link but Stackoverflow won't let me...)

Comment: Hello - isn't it difficult to build an application not knowing what the real data looks like ? - how do you get around it ?

Answer (score 1):

http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Rate-limiting contains lots of information, including this;

"The default rate limit for calls to the REST API is 150 requests per hour. The REST API does account- and IP-based rate limiting. Authenticated API calls are charged to the authenticating user's limit while unauthenticated API calls are deducted from the calling IP address' allotment."

Answer (score 1):

The rates are significantly lower than what they used to be. There is no more white listing, and most API calls are now 15 per 15 minutes. In addition there is a cap of calls per hour at 100, and an additional ceiling for things like direct messages; they are also limited to 1000 per 24 hours.

Answer (score -1):

It is 100 calls per IP or per user. and the Limit was recently increased to either 125 or 150.

If you have a Twitter Application that comes from a single IP, like a web application, you can get your IP/Account Whitelisted, allow for 10,000 calls per hour.

Answer (score -1):

It's 100 calls per user, not per application.

[link text](http://tweetdeck.posterous.com/what-does-rate-limit-exceeded)

Answer (score -1):

It's most likely 100 calls per IP per hour.  I doubt there's a reliable way for them to track which application is making the request.

Comment: It's incredibly simple, especially since they are now using OAuth. They also state that they use both account and IP for bans, which means multiple servers authenticating tells them enough to block the requests.

Comment: :) Yea, this answer is quite out of date now, isn't it?  2009 was a long time ago...